# Need to frame an expression to activate a button

Tags: siebel

I need to implement the following logic to activate a button.
But i am unable to come up with an expression for it.

Logic is as follows:

1. Check if the account has an inactive agreement.
2. If so, search for the latest submitted order placed before an interrupt order.
3. Look whether that order has any multi term quotes.
4. If so, check whether any one of the multi term quotes has "Approved" Status.

The Button has to be activated only when these conditions are met.
Could anyone pls help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to write eScript at BC level, you will be able to compose the various conditions easily.
If you want a calculated field expression for this at Account BC, you will need to connect the other BCs via MVLs to Account BC.
Then you could use the [EXISTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/ToolsDevRef/operators_conditions9.html) function in calc fields.EXITS returns true if at least one record exists satisfying the condition

EXISTS ([Agreement Status]='Inactive' AND [Latest Order Quote Status]='Approved')

You will have to provide more Calc Fields on Order BC to find its Quote Status, which will be pulled up to Account